# python: 16 byte token generation for authentication

Tags: python, random

In python, I need to generate 16 byte(specific due to machine constraints) token for authentication. What would be best way to do it:

- os.urandom: which takes exactly the number of bytes as argument to return same number of random bytes. Will this be a good option if same machine generates many such random number simultaneously ?
- uuid.uuid4: Does the str(uuid.uuid4()) is of 16 byte(if not, can we use uuid to generate 16 byte)?

Comment: Note that `uuid.uuid4()` *will use `os.urandom()`* unless `libuuid` is available. `libuuid` also [uses `/dev/urandom` if available](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_generate.3.html).

Comment: `uuid4` is not completely random: a part of this number signifies that it is indeed a UUID version 4, so in effect, it only has 122 bits of randomness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants_and_versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uuid.uuid4()` generates 16 random bytes (using the system urandom if available), but the output is longer than 16 bytes after it is converted to printable ASCII. Do you need 16 bytes of random data, or 16 printable bytes? Using it for a token suggests the latter. In that case you will need to truncate it (using the end rather than the beginning, as there are some non-random versioning bytes at the start, and stripping hyphens as they do you no good) and realize that you have less than 16 bytes worth of randomness.

Or, base64-encode random data yourself. You can fit more into 16 bytes with b64 than b16 (hex) that uuid uses (12 bytes vs 8)

[urandom implementations are OS specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random). Generally urandom is non-blocking and uses a PRNG that is seeded with available entropy.

Comment: Jason: Any comment on concurrent generation of token string using urandom ?